# java print list of items using recursion seems inefficient

Tags: java, list, recursion

I am doing a pretty basic assignment. "Use recursion to print the values of a list" and I came up with the code below, but as it passes the list EVERY time it calls itself I wondered if there is a better way. Any advice please?

```
public class RecurList {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list = {8,7,9,10,56};

    int ix = list.length;
    int sumNow = ShowNext(ix, 0, list);  // initial call -> sum is 0

    System.out.println("Recursion total is " + sumNow);
}   
    public static int ShowNext(int inx, int sum, int[] lst) {
        if (inx == 0) return sum;
        int item = lst[inx - 1];
        sum += item;
        System.out.println("inx:" + inx + " item:" + item + " sum:" + sum);
        return ShowNext(inx - 1, sum, lst);
    }
```

}

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes; pass only the remainder of the list.  Look up basic recursion on lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read and follow [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Start your method names with a lowercase letter.

> "Use recursion to print the values of a list"

You failed that assignment since you're using an *array* instead of a list.

> it passes the list EVERY time it calls itself I wondered if there is a better way.

There are two solutions to this problem.

The more intentional approach is what @Prune suggested: shorten the list (which is an array in your case) by one element.  The utility class `Arrays` has methods to do this.

The lesser "recursive" style is to make the array a class member and remove it from the methods parameter list:

```
 public class RecurList {
    static int[] list; 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    list = {8,7,9,10,56};

    int ix = list.length;
    int sumNow = ShowNext(ix, 0);  // initial call -> sum is 0

    System.out.println("Recursion total is " + sumNow);
  }   
  public static int ShowNext(int inx, int sum) {
        if (inx == 0) return sum;
        int item = lst[inx - 1];
        sum += item;
        System.out.println("inx:" + inx + " item:" + item + " sum:" + sum);
        return ShowNext(inx - 1, sum);
    }
}
```